# Are there ways to build mathematics without axiomatizing?

Tags: logic, soft-question, philosophy

Every time I read about a theory in mathematics, it usually starts with axiomatizing the most fundamental concepts that are going to be treated.

Recently, I have started finding this troubling. In the foundational crisis, we tried to root all of mathematics on set theory and build it up from there. I believe this is a supremely elegant idea, but I have to ask myself why.

I understand why axioms are the brick wall against which all infinite regressions crash. We cannot, after all, ask why something is indefinitely. There must come a time when we simply say: because it is.

But why? What happens if we throw logic out of the window and attempt to start everything from scratch?

I have read about model and category theory and all types of order logics, but none of them seem to be enough because they are all rooted in something that eventually leads to a so-called "self-evident truth". What if infinite regressions are similar to infinite series: something that at first we assumed was non sensical but actually turns out to be really useful?

My question is: are there ways to build mathematics without axiomatizing? If no, is there a proof?

Comment: Well, *if* we throw logic out of the window, *then*...

Comment: ... oh, sh*t!${}{}$ (:P)

Comment: How do we know what "works" without logic?

Comment: @G. Sassatelli: ... we can [grok](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grok).

Comment: See [Quine](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quine/#QuiNatImp) and [Holism](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/meaning-holism/).

Comment: "What happens if we throw logic out of the window and attempt to start everything from scratch?" But again, to lay new "foundations" you have again to start from somwhere using some "tools" to argument and so on. Thus, you can "reform" logic itself (see [Intuitionsim](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/)) but you need some sort of logic again.

Comment: You are mixing up logic and a very Platonist view of the axiomatic method. We need logic to know how to make deductions from hypotheses. We need axioms as interesting initial hypotheses. We don't need to assume that the axioms of set theory or any other foundational system are self-evident truths. Nor we do need to "build" mathematics: instead we just do it, i.e., we follow the process of rigorously drawing mathematically interesting conclusions from mathematically  interesting hypotheses.

Comment: We can use logic to design and build for example electronics and electronics is very useful for many purposes. For example it allows us to communicate efficiently all over the world regarding it's usefulness.

Comment: Also see http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1808558 for an explanation of what is needed for the meta-system to talk about or prove various things about formal systems. Since the meta-system itself is a formal system, it presents a bootstrap problem but at least an understanding of what is needed for what will tell us why PRA is a reasonable choice of meta-system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember reading the abstract of an article (or description of a book perhaps) that claimed to answer this using the principles of evolutionary biology; essentially, the author performed various simulations suggesting that organisms that take, as their fundamental logic, anything other than $2$-valued boolean logic tend to die off in the long run. I think if you Google around, you'll probably be able to dig something up in that vein.

One might object: ah, but you're using classical logic to build computer simulations and interpret the result of those simulations. That's circular! My gut feeling is that actually, this isn't circular (but my thoughts on this aren't sufficiently well-developed that its worth me trying to write them here.)

Comment: Can you remember anything more on the article? I would like to read it but google searches return nothing

Comment: @GuachoPerez, I think [this](http://www.cambridge.org/au/academic/subjects/philosophy/philosophy-science/evolution-reason-logic-branch-biology) might be it.

Answer (score 1):

Gödels incompleteness theorems are widely interpreted to mean that it is impossible to construct a reasoning system that can prove itself to be consistent. As such, it is almost universally believed that it is impossible to construct mathemathics without starting with some "self evident" axioms.

[The Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems) explains the details of the theorems better than I can hope to do here and also includes sketches for various methods of proving the theorems.

Comment: Like the OP you are taking a very Platonist view of the axiomatic method. The axioms of group theory, for example, aren't self-evident truths, but are useful hypotheses to take as the starting point for mathematical investigation. Axiomatisations of foundational systems like set theory are no different in character from axiomatisations of group theory from a mathematical point of view (even if you don't "believe" in principles like the axiom of  choice, you can still reason about the consequences of those principles).

Comment: It is trivial to construct a reasoning system that proves itself to be consistent.  Just construct an inconsistent reasoning system.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematics is about ideas (sometimes really great ideas) which must be formulated, because there are no visible mathematical objects in reality to rely on. We formulate these ideas using some human language enriched with mathematical symbols and definitions (also possible to express in human languages).

The primary mathematical definition is 'mathematical statement'. Ordinary statements are often vague with a lot of implicit, unstated information attached to it and interpreted differently depending on personality and circumstances because reality is too complex, while mathematical statements about formal models is true or not true.

All mathematics is about formal models and all formal models is defined by axioms. Logic works when used intelligent, because it is consistent. Any consistent system will work for those who know how to use it.

Sitting at a table with the pieces of a puzzle, litterally och figuratively, it works to use a consistant system of classification: it brings order and progress. Logic includes rules to classify statements as true or not true in a consistant way.

Answer (score 0):

We don't know that know that the logic we are using works.  There are an uncountable number of possible logical systems and there can't be a logical reason to select one logical system over another.

The decision to select a logical system is more the result of history and capacity to create results that are useful and pleasing to mathematicians.

Comment: Hopefully for other people as well. Physics, for example, is based on mathematics. If the results predicted by the logic are not those measured, than the axioms are wrong

Comment: We don't know that know that....??